# How do I change part of a string in an attribute value using XSLT with Python and LXML?

Tags: python, xml, xslt

I have to process a bunch of XML documents that have structures similar to the following:

```
<tok xpos="ABCDE">node1</tok> <tok xpos="XYZ">node2</tok>
<tok xpos="ABCDE">node6</tok> <tok xpos="RST">node7</tok>
<tok xpos="ABTSV">node8</tok> <tok xpos="XYU">node9</tok>
<tok xpos="ABTSV">node14</tok> <tok xpos="XBZ">node15</tok>
```

So, what I need to do is to change part of the value for the attribute 'xpos' just in case the value for the same attribute in the following element starts with a specific sequence of characters. So, in this example, I would need to replace the first two characters of the value for any 'xpos' attribute starting with 'AB' with a new value that will replace 'AB' with 'XX' and will preserve the rest of the characters in the string just in case a specific condition is met. This condition being that the value of the 'xpos' attribute in the following element starts with the sequence of characters 'XY'.

So, after processing, the output would have to be:

```
<tok xpos="XXCDE">node1</tok> <tok xpos="XYZ">node2</tok> 
<tok xpos="ABCDE">node6</tok> <tok xpos="RST">node7</tok>
<tok xpos="XXTSV">node8</tok> <tok xpos="XYU">node9</tok>
<tok xpos="ABTSV">node14</tok> <tok xpos="XBZ">node15</tok>
```

Following the suggestions of a helpful stackoverflow contributor I tried to use XSLT with the following code:

```
# coding: utf-8
import os
import lxml.etree as et
import time


ROOT = '/Users/somepath'
ext = ('.xml')

def xml_change(root_element):
    et.XSLT(et.XML('''  
    <xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:re="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
        exclude-result-prefixes="re"
        version="1.0">
        
        <xsl:param name="pattern">^(AB)([A-Z]+)</xsl:param>
        <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="tok[re:match(@xpos, '^(AB)([A-Z]+)')][following-sibling::tok[1][starts-with(@xpos, 'XY')]]/@xpos">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="re:replace(., $pattern, '', 'XX$2')"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet> 
    '''))
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ROOT):

    for file in files:
        
        if file.endswith(ext):
            
            file_path = os.path.join(ROOT, file)
            # load root element from file
            file_root = et.parse(file_path).getroot()
            # init tree object from file_root
            xml_change(file_root)
            tree = et.ElementTree(file_root)

            # save cleaned xml tree object to file. Important to specify encoding                
            tree.write(file_path.replace('.xml', '-clean.xml'), encoding='utf-8', pretty_print=True, doctype='<!DOCTYPE document SYSTEM "estcorpus.dtd">', xml_declaration=True)
```

This doesn't seem to work but I don't know exactly why. The documents appear to be processed and I get the copies of the files with the added '-clean' in their names. I don't get any error messages but nothing seems to have changed inside the documents.

EDIT: After reading the answers, I changed the relevant parts of my code to:

```
xslt_job=et.XML('''  
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tok[starts-with(@xpos, 'AB')][starts-with(following-sibling::tok[1]/@xpos, 'XY')]/@xpos">
     <xsl:attribute name="xpos">
        <xsl:text>XX</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 3)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
    ''')
transform = et.XSLT(xslt_job)
# iterate all dirs
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ROOT):
        
        if file.endswith(ext):            
            file_path = os.path.join(ROOT, file)
            file_root = et.parse(file_path).getroot()
            result_tree = transform(file_root)             
            result_tree.write(file_path.replace('.xml', '-clean.xml'), encoding='utf-8', doctype='<!DOCTYPE document SYSTEM "estcorpus.dtd">', xml_declaration=True)
```

I'm happy because it seems that this is finally working (i.e. the newly created files contain the desired transformations). However, there is one problem: the structure of the original documents disappears in the output XML documents which contain all a single line. I know there is a way to fix that by adding the parameter "pretty_print=True" to the write command but this won't work for me. This parameter renders well formed XML docs but the documents need to preserve exactly the structure of the originals. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I would compile that stylesheet once and then apply it to each input. But your current code simply lacks any call of/use of the function you have written, anyway. And the XSLT transformation doesn't update the input tree, you get a result tree your function should return and that you can then save with e.g. write_output.

Comment: You don't really need xslt for that. A couple of lines with lxml should be enough.

Comment: Sorry @Martin, the function was actually called in the code. Since my code contained a lot of counters and other irrelevant stuff I had cleaned it before I posted it here and by mistake I had deleted the line where the function is called. I have added it now. It still does not work. It doesn't work with the changes suggested by michael, either. I will try to compile it as you suggest.

Comment: Thanks @JackFleeting. I'm aware of that. I'm trying to do it with XSLT because it seems to be way more powerful. Even though now it might seem an overkill, my reasoning is that it might be worth it learning how to do it this way so that in the future I can extend it to solve more complex problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the parsing of the stylesheet outside and before the function e.g.

```
transform = et.XSLT(et.XML('''  
    <xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:re="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
        exclude-result-prefixes="re"
        version="1.0">
        
        <xsl:param name="pattern">^(AB)([A-Z]+)</xsl:param>
        <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="tok[re:match(@xpos, '^(AB)([A-Z]+)')][following-sibling::tok[1][starts-with(@xpos, 'XY')]]/@xpos">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="re:replace(., $pattern, '', 'XX$2')"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet> 
    '''))
```

Then use e.g.

```
def xml_change(root_element):
    return transform(root_element)
```

and e.g.

```
result_tree = xml_change(file_root)
```

then to save that use the documented write_output e.g.

```
result_tree.write_output(ile_path.replace('.xml'))
```

Make sure your XSLT sets any wanted encoding and DOCTYPE/system id with e.g. `<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-system="estcorpus.dtd"/>`

Comment: Thanks again @Martin. It looks like you were writing your answer while I was editing my original post. Not in the exact way you suggest but I managed to solve the problems I had encountered. Alas, as I say in the edit, now I'm loosing the original structure of the documents that I needed to preserve.

Comment: Well, in my comment to your previous question's comment I suggested you start with the lxm XSLT documentation; also, in this answer, I have suggested, like they do there, to use the `write_output` method. So please try that.

Comment: Thanks for your enormous patience @Martin. I replaced all the relevant parts of my code with the exact code you suggested and now everything works exactly as I needed it to work. Thanks again!!

Comment: One curious thing happened. I don't know whether this is important or not but I notice that the newly created documents have a slight change in one of the headings. Whereas the original document had <!DOCTYPE document SYSTEM "estcorpus.dtd">, the new output documents have <!DOCTYPE TEI SYSTEM "estcorpus.dtd">

Comment: @jfontana, the root element name determines what belongs as the name of `DOCTYPE ..`, thus, if the root element is `TEI`, then the DOCTYPE declaration will say `DOCTYPE TEI`. As with your other comments and follow-up questions, if you are uncertain on how to decide or achieve the result for such an issue, then address it in a separate question, focussing on the issue. Here you asked about using the Python API to run XSLT 1 with lxml and I think that is solved. Any problems regarding a particular XSLT transformation issue should be dealt with in separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your stylesheet will likely return an error because the libxslt processor does not support the EXSLT Regular Expressions extension functions.

The stated task can be actually accomplished quite easily without any extension functions. Given a well-formed input such as:

**XML**

```
<root>
 <tok xpos="XXCDE">node1</tok> <tok xpos="XYZ">node2</tok>
 <tok xpos="ABCDE">node6</tok> <tok xpos="RST">node7</tok>
 <tok xpos="XXTSV">node8</tok> <tok xpos="XYU">node9</tok>
 <tok xpos="ABTSV">node14</tok> <tok xpos="XBZ">node15</tok>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tok[starts-with(@xpos, 'AB')][starts-with(following-sibling::tok[1]/@xpos, 'XY')]/@xpos">
     <xsl:attribute name="xpos">
        <xsl:text>XX</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 3)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
 <tok xpos="XXCDE">node1</tok> <tok xpos="XYZ">node2</tok>
 <tok xpos="ABCDE">node6</tok> <tok xpos="RST">node7</tok>
 <tok xpos="XXTSV">node8</tok> <tok xpos="XYU">node9</tok>
 <tok xpos="ABTSV">node14</tok> <tok xpos="XBZ">node15</tok>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k. Your stylesheet works perfectly but apparently so does the other one. I appreciate seeing another way of doing it that doesn't require any extensions, though.

Comment: Then you're lucky to have a version that supports the extension functions (mine doesn't).

Comment: P.S. I have updated my answer to preserve the original indentation.